# The mother grips her son's hand [in/of/on] crossing the road?

Tags: prepositions, in-of

What is the correct preposition?

The mother grips her son's hand [in/of/on] crossing the road?

Comment: The preposition in the sentence should be "on".

Comment: In contemporary American English, most speakers would probably say *holds her son's hand when crossing* or *while crossing* the road.  "...grips ... *on* crossing" means she grabs onto her son's hand *as they begin to cross*, whereas *while* and *when* convey the idea of holding hands during the crossing.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+on+crossing+the+road%2Cwhen+crossing+the+road%2Cwhile+crossing+the+road&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20crossing%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20crossing%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%20crossing%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrected sentence would be:

> The mother holds her son's hand on crossing the road.

I chose *'hold'* instead of *'grip'* just because I'm not sure you can use *'grip'*. But I may be wrong. But the answer to your question is *'on'*. Alternatively, you could rephrase it as :

> 1. The mother holds her son's hand **while** crossing the road.

Comment: *Grip* is perfect and can be used.